# Nhibernate Criteria Group By clause and select other data that is not grouped

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have a parent child relationship, let's say class and children. Each child belongs to a class and has a grade. I need to select the children (or the ids of the children) with the lowest grade per class.

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Classs))
 .CreateAlias("Children", "children")
 .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
     .Add(Projections.Min("children.Grade"))
     .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Id"))
 )
 .List<Object[]>();
```

This query returns me the lowest grade per class, but I don't know which child got the grade. When I add the children's Id to the group, the group is wrong and every child gets returned.

I was hoping we could just get the id's of those childs without grouping them. If this is not possible, then maybe there is a way to solve this with subqueries?

Comment: How do you want to handle the situation where multiple children tie for the lowest grade?  Just take the first, take them all, or use some other criteria?

Comment: Well, the class <-> children example was to make it more understandable. In my case the grade is more like a priority/order and a tie is impossible. (Unless offcouse we would insert it manually in our database, but this is not imporatant since we will not do that :) )

Comment: Peter, did you end up solving this? We have the same issue...

Comment: @6footunder see if the answer below can help

Answer (score 1):

if min grade is unique:

```
select (select id from child c where c.classs_id = classs.id and c.grade = Min(classs.grade)) as child_id, classs.id from classs join child group by classs.id
```

transalted to Criteria

```
subquery = detachedCriteria.For<Child>("this")
  .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("this.Classs", "classs.Id"))
  .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("this.Grade", Projections.Min("classs.Grade")))
  .SetProjection(Projections.Id())


session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Classs), "classs")
  .CreateAlias("Children", "children")
  .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
     .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.SubQuery(subquery)), "child_id")
     .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Id"))
  )
  .List<object[]>()     // contains child_id and id (classs)
```

i cant test it right now, but you should get the idea